# Scroll a quarter (25%) of the screen up or down

Tags: cursor-movement, scrolling

I often find scrolling a full page too disorienting, half a page too much, but a quarter page is just right. I currently do it just by holding down the arrow keys.

How do I scroll 25% of the page down and up easily?

Comment: check the crossed out function in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3102890

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Maybe <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> could be what you are looking for. By default they move half of the screen.

From [`:h CTRL-D`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/scroll.txt.html#CTRL%2DD):

> Scroll window Downwards in the buffer.  The number of
>   lines comes from the 'scroll' option (default: half a
>   screen).
>
> If [count] given, first set 'scroll' option
>   to [count].

Which means that the first time you want to scroll in a window you can do <kbd>XX</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> where XX is the 25% of the number of lines in your window. As it sets `scroll` to the XX value you can then use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> to move 25% of the screen.

Also, I think that [`:h scrolling`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/scroll.txt.html#scrolling) might be interesting for you.

---

**Edit**

And here is another solution with a function and some mappings to add to your `.vimrc`:

```
function! ScrollQuarter(move)
    let height=winheight(0)

    if a:move == 'up'
        let key="\<C-Y>"
    else
        let key="\<C-E>"
    endif

    execute 'normal! ' . height/4 . key
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <up> :call ScrollQuarter('up')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <down> :call ScrollQuarter('down')<CR>
```

The function will get the height of the current window, and accordingly to its parameter will scroll the screen up or down of a quarter of the height.

The mappings will call the function, the first one to go up and the second one to go down.

Of course, you can change `<up>` and `<down>` to some other keys if you want to keep the default behavior of your arrow keys.

Comment: Seems like it might make more sense to use `ctrl-E` and `ctrl-Y` in the mappings, because a). you then have separate shortcuts for both 1/2 page and 1/4 page scrolling. b). the behaviour of `ctrl-U`/`ctrl-D` is consistent and not dependent on whether you have previously used the mapping.

Comment: I don't understand your important note. What do you mean enter manually? Currently using this deletes a line instead of moving the page.

Comment: @LouisHong See the line `let key="^U"` the part between the double quote is meant to represent the key code of `ctrl+u`. So if you copied the function in vim put your cursor on the first double quote hit `ci"` to modify the content of the quotes and then hit `ctrl+v` followed by `ctrl+u` to the same on the line `let key="^D"`.

Comment: @Rich: Yup that's a good point. I used the arrow keys because that's what OP said he used but your point is relevant.

Comment: @statox You misunderstood me! (I wasn't clear). I meant use `let key="^Y"` instead of `let key="^U"`. It will create the same behaviour but without affecting the `'scroll'` setting.

Comment: @Rich: Indeed I misunderstood you but your point makes even more sense now :-) Note that I'm used to navigate with motions/search/tags but not really with these scrolling commands which might explain why I choosed `^U` instead of `^Y`

Comment: @statox I think you were [primed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_(psychology)) to use `^U/^D` because of your original answer. Either way, I like your answer now!

Comment: @Rich So today I learned about a psychological concept that I didn't know and someone like my answer: that's a good day ;-)

Comment: How can I reset CTRL-D and CTRL-U to the default scroll behavior?

Comment: @MartinBraun From [`:h 'scroll'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27scroll%27): `Reset to half the window height with ":set scroll=0".`

Answer (score 6):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to move the page by one line up and down.

Then if you want for +/- 25% to be moved you can use <kbd>20</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> and that will move you 20 lines down.

Here is also a good explained question that is similiar to yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458689/how-to-move-screen-without-moving-cursor-in-vim

Answer (score 3):

I variated **statox** approach so it scrolls more consistent over the linewraps.
If you want a quarter step, change 0.618 back to 0.25 or whatever.

```
function! ScrollGolden(move)
    let height=winheight(0)
    if a:move == 'up'
        let prep='L'
        " let key="^Y"
        let key='gk'
        let post='zb'
    elseif a:move == 'down'
        let prep='H'
        " let key="^E"
        let key='gj'
        let post='zt'
    endif
    execute 'normal! ' . prep . float2nr(round(height*0.618)) . key . post
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> <BS>    :call ScrollGolden('up')<CR>
nnoremap <silent> <Space> :call ScrollGolden('down')<CR>
```

Answer (score 2):

If your wanting a good general answer and not an exact 25% you could factor the normal line count on a page by divide by 25 and set some system mappings. For instance if you normally have about 100 line on a screen at a time then 25% of that is 25 lines so you could set a key mapping on something like your capital J and K for quickly moving up and down 25 lines

```
noremap J 25j
noremap K 25k
```

If your wanting to just jump to the quarter mark of the entire file then in normal mode just type:

```
25%
```

Comment: I think there's two drawback with your solution: `noremap J 25j` hardcodes the value `25` thus when for example you horizontally split a 100 lines window your mapping will actually navigate 50% of the new windows. About your second option `:25%` I didn't knew it existed but from my tests it seems that it puts the cursor on a position based on the first line: if I have a 100 lines buffer and I want to move 25% forward typing `:25%` will bring me on line 25 no matter where my cursor was. Also could you please put the help topic describing this feature I can't find it in the doc?

Comment: I found the help topic at [`:h N%`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#N%25) :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here are simple one-line mappings that don't require a separate function.  Putting these in your .vimrc will cause CTRL-j and CTRL-k to respectively move down or up 1/4 of the screen in insert, visual, and normal modes.

```
" insert mode
inoremap <expr> <C-j> '<ESC>'.winheight(0)/4.'<C-D>a'
inoremap <expr> <C-k> '<ESC>'.winheight(0)/4.'<C-U>a'

" visual mode
vnoremap <expr> <C-j> winheight(0)/4.'<C-D>'
vnoremap <expr> <C-k> winheight(0)/4.'<C-U>'

" normal mode
nnoremap <expr> <C-j> winheight(0)/4.'<C-D>'
nnoremap <expr> <C-k> winheight(0)/4.'<C-U>'
```

Adapted from  [this Reddit answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/guldlq/comment/fsjdu47/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

**Bonus:** Combine with the [vim-smoothie](https://github.com/psliwka/vim-smoothie) plugin for animated smooth scrolling. If do this, replace `inoremap` with `imap`, `vnoremap` with `vmap`, and `nnoremap` with `nmap` to allow nested overrides of the keybindings.