# Keep `scroll` equal to current window height

Tags: autocmd, scrolling

Is there a way to update `scroll` every time window height changes?

I know, that I can achieve the same behavior calling `winheight(0)` on each <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> press as suggested [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/10031/scroll-a-quarter-25-of-the-screen-up-or-down), but I'm curious if there is another way.

Comment: I nerver used it so I'm not sure how convenient that would be but there is an autocommand event `VimResized` which could be interesting for you [`:h VimResized`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#VimResized)